# Vertical Line Plot based on Actual Calendar Days not based on Bar Index

Tags: calendar, line, days

Need help in Pine script to Plot vertical line at certain intervals & starting at given date,  if Saturday, sunday come in between then also consider them.

i have written it based on bar index but its ignoring week offs (where no candle exist) and not consider not actual calendar days

Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.